# When building a search engine web crawler, what site should it start on to crawl the entire internet?

Tags: web-crawler, search-engine

I am trying to build a search engine for that one of the major component is a web crawler, I am stuck at the point that in beginning from where the crawler will start crawling. It needs a webpage to crawl.  What should be the very first web page?

Comment: The home page I suppose

Comment: There's no specific website to crawl, I will be building my own db of links (something like Google for eg). So at point zero(when there is no entries in my db) there will be nothing to show. I will have to start and crawling somewhere, stuck on where to start

Comment: Well, in that case you have to manually add websites to your crawler. Also, I don't think google adds a website to its results just because they exist on the internet. The owner of the website adds it to the index of google so that it can crawl your website willingly.

Comment: yeah I know that aspect, thanks @SumitJaiswal, will add manually

Answer (score 1):

You want to pick a page that has enough links on it that you will eventually be able to crawl the entire internet.  Many sites don't have any external links, so it is important to choose a site that does the opposite.  You want a site that links to thousands or millions of other sites.

Options include:

- Directory websites - Traditionally the open directory project (DMOZ) was the go-to seed for many web crawlers.   However it has now shut down.   You could still seed your crawler with its data or with one of the other sites that has opened to take its place.
- News aggregation sites - There are several big sites that collect tons and tons links to other sites (like reddit).
- User generated forum or question and answer sites - Sites (like this one) could be a good starting place because users on them link to many external resources.
- Online encyclopedias - Wikipedia has tons of external links the references section for its articles

You probably don't want to limit yourself to just one option.   I would seed my crawler with several starting sites.

Three of the sources I listed above (dmoz, stack exchange, wikipedia) have ways that you can download all their data in a dump.  You might even want to start with the data dumps to save your crawler a significant amount of work crawling those specific sites.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good options, didn't know about DMOZ will start from that